# Gitlab Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)

Tags: debian, ssl, git, gitlab

I'm having some problems that I hadn't before with Gitlab and Git.

I updated my SSL on my Debian server as I usually do each year and `git` doesn't work as intended anymore

Apache Web Server and Gitlab CE hosted website are working well with HTTPS.

I verify SSL config attempts with `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect mysite.com:port` and getting the code 21 always except when I run the command inside the server. [Log from another PC](https://pastebin.com/97HsANMD) [Log from localhost](https://pastebin.com/XFU82Fy0)

---

- Debian 9 up-to-date
- Gitlab CE latest version
- GIT 2.11

Output of `git config http.sslCAPath`:

```
/etc/ssl/ (before /etc/ssl/certs)
```

How can I debug better this situation?

> Please avoid typing `git config --global http.sslVerify false`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've concatenated the certificates in your certificate chain out of order. Your certificate comes first, followed by the intermediate certificate. But you have these reversed.

You also should *not* include the CA certificate in your chain. But your chain includes it.

Rebuild your certificate chain, including only your certificate followed by the intermediate certificates.

Consider using a service such as [Qualys SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=tecalis.com) to test your configuration.

Comment: Do you mean to only concat these two file `COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt` with `COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt`?
How do I refresh the configuration? `git config --global http.sslCAInfo /etc/ssl/new.crt` will work?


I use that service but in this case git is blocked outside my home.

Comment: No, you DO NOT include the CA certificate. As shown in your report, AddTrust External CA should NOT be included.

Comment: I updated the OP with an image of my certs, which ones should I use? I tried with https://whatsmychaincert.com/ but no success. Uploaded it to `/etc/ssl/certs` and then did `update-ca-certificates`

Comment: @Novo Again, you use only your domain certificate and the intermediate certificates. You do NOT include the root CA certificate. Did you not click the link?

Comment: Michael, I can't try "Qualys SSL Server Test" because my firewall blocks all ports except http/https outside my network.

Comment: @Novo Good thing it's https, then! So why can't you try it?

Comment: As I said in the OP, Apache and Gitlab CI web instance works well, but `git push` doesn't :S
BTW Gitlab is mounted in port 9000 and it's blocked outside my network too

Comment: So what's stopping you from visiting that web site and reading it?